# remove the view and load another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to remove view after the click of the button and load another view the code which I am trying to explain you which is below

```
[self removeFromSuperview];
FZforgetpassword *forget=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"FZforgetpassword" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
forget.delegate=self;
forget.frame=self.bounds;
[forget showCustomView:4];
[self addSubview:forget];
```

first line I am removing the view and then loading the another view but I am not getting the second view when I run this code

Comment: Are you using auto layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
//add subview first
FZforgetpassword *forget=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"FZforgetpassword" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
forget.delegate=self;
forget.frame=self.bounds;
[forget showCustomView:4];
[self addSubview:forget];
//finally remove 'self view'
[self removeFromSuperview];
```

note: if you remove 'self' first then '[self addSubview:forget];' can't be executed. because now 'self = nil'

Answer (score 0):

This remove self from superview, it will be deallocated if you don't have any reference to it:

```
[self removeFromSuperview];
```